# How can i update to different value in each of nested list

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

So i have following document in collection:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f3f7a44e9cb27622304f889"
  },
  "date": "21.08.2020",
  "orgPin": "e3jINZgIjhRyY58nLd1lrRz6",
  "process": [
    {
  "periodPin":"u3IpP5Wsq13Woi4dFYET07PX5KDE5V6c",
      "fullStartDate": {
    "$date": "2020-08-21T11:39:48.000Z"
      },
      "checkedBy": "C0D5B93D-A373-4EDF-B5A7-4A58C6EC8C88",
      "workList": [
         {
          "workId": "5f0fff55dc86bc42746ad717",
          "status": 1,
          "description": "",
        },
        {
          "workId": "5f0fff55dc86bc42746ad71a",
          "status": 1,
          "description": "",
        },
        {
          "workId": "5f0fff55dc86bc42746ad71f",
          "status": 1,
          "description": "",
        },
        {
          "workId": "5f0fff55dc86bc42746ad721",
         "status": 1,
          "description": "",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

i have another object in back-end (python):

```
{
  '5f0fff55dc86bc42746ad71f': 'Baku',
  '5f0fff55dc86bc42746ad71a': 'Qarachukhur'
}
```

So i want to change "description" to 'Baku' where "workId" equals to "5f0fff55dc86bc42746ad71f" and change  "description" to 'Qarachukhur' where "workId" equals to "5f0fff55dc86bc42746ad71a".
I can do it in loop in python but it is not suitable to best practice. Please help me to solve this problem with one query in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

> bulkWrite() takes an array of write operations and executes each of them. By default operations are executed in order.

You have different conditions to update documents. As you said, it is not efficient to update in a loop i.e one by one update statements.

But you can do `bulk write`. Loop it in the backend and prepare all the update statements and send it in single bulk write. Advantage of this is that it is efficient and reduces network round trip time. And that's the purpose of bulk write also.

[Refer documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

**Syntax from doc:** - single query to the server from client point of view.

```
db.collection.bulkWrite( [
   { updateOne :
      {
         "filter": <document>,
         "update": <document or pipeline>,            // Changed in 4.2
         "upsert": <boolean>,
         "collation": <document>,                     // Available starting in 3.4
         "arrayFilters": [ <filterdocument1>, ... ],  // Available starting in 3.6
         "hint": <document|string>                    // Available starting in 4.2.1
      }
   }
] )
```

You can have multiple `updateOne` statements. Not only `updateOne` but also many `update operators` i.e update, replace..

Comment: Hi, my friend, thank you, i understood this bulkWrite. But how can i use array_filter -parameter with bulkWrite? in pymongo

Comment: It has an option. Please refer the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

## I found solution of the problem

I want to say something before: 
In this example i will share part of my web API (which is we need) and i need some data from front-end developer. The data is like it:

```
{
  "orgPin": "e3jINZgIjhRyY58nLd1lrRz6",
  "periodPin": "u3IpP5Wsq13Woi4dFYET07PX5KDE5V6c",
  "doneWorkList": [
    {
      "workId": "5f0fff55dc86bc42746ad717",
      "status": 2
    },
    {
      "workId": "5f0fff55dc86bc42746ad71f",
      "status": 1
    },
    {
      "workId": "5f0fff55dc86bc42746ad71a",
      "status": 4,
      "description": "FRFR"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I need to update some `"status"` value with the help of `"workId"`. I'll also add `"description"` parameters to the appropriate object.

What we can do?

At first you must make the list for this query and then paste the list to `bulkWrite`. In my example i use `pymongo` tool. In `pymongo` `bulkWrite` using as `bulk_write` and inside it we will use `UpdateOne` tool of `pymongo`. At first we must import `pymongo` and `UpdateOne` (wee need also must import `MongoClient` for connection to database):

```
import pymongo,
from pymongo import UpdateOne, MongoClient
```

Then we need connection to database:

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.test_database
```

So, now wee need to connect to collection:

```
collection = db.test_collection
```

Now we in important issue. We must make the method which is make a list query for us:

```
def bulk_write_query(search, work_id, status, interval_pin, description=None):
update_query = {
    'process.$[arg1].workList.$[arg2].status': status
}
if description is not None:
    update_query.update({'process.$[arg1].workList.$[arg2].description': description})
array_filters_list = [
    {"arg1.periodPin": interval_pin},
    {"arg2.workId": work_id}
]

big_query = UpdateOne(
    search,
    {'$set': update_query},
    upsert=False,
    array_filters=array_filters_list
)
return big_query
```

And we need some variables in main code place:

```
search_event = {
                  "date": "21.08.2020",
                  "orgPin": "e3jINZgIjhRyY58nLd1lrRz6"
                }
 interval_pin = "u3IpP5Wsq13Woi4dFYET07PX5KDE5V6c"
```

At finally important part of our code:

```
query_list = list(map(lambda x: bulk_write_query(search_daily, x['workId'], x['status'], interval_pin) if 'description' not in x else bulk_write_query(search_daily, x['workId'], x['status'], interval_pin, x['description']) or x, done_work_list))

result = collection.bulk_write(query_list)
print(result.bulk_api_result)
```

Here is finish! I printed result of process with `result.bulk_api_result` at the end. Have a nice job!